# UITableView load more when scrolling to bottom like Facebook application

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, pagination

I am developing an application that uses SQLite. I want to show a list of users (UITableView) using a paginating mechanism. Could any one please tell me how to load more data in my list when the user scrolls to the end of the list (like on home page on Facebook application)?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can do that by adding a check on where you're at in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. This method is easy to understand and to implement :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Classic start method
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MainMenuCellIdentifier];
    }

    MyData *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Do your cell customisation
    // cell.titleLabel.text = data.title;

    BOOL lastItemReached = [data isEqual:[[self.dataArray] lastObject]]; 
    if (!lastItemReached && indexPath.row == [self.dataArray count] - 1)
    {
        [self launchReload];
    }
}
```

EDIT : added a check on last item to prevent recursion calls. You'll have to implement the method defining whether the last item has been reached or not.

EDIT2 : explained lastItemReached

Comment: What if user scrolls up and down, so cellForRowAtIndexPath is called MANY TIMES !??

Comment: First time he scrolls to the bottom his list will be reloaded. And each time he hits the bottom a new chunk of data will be gathered. If any specific treatment has to be applied, it will be `launchReload` method's responsibility to handle it (for exemple, only one asynchronous reload action at a time)

Comment: I had to add a flag to prevent a recursion issue when the last item was hit: `if !lastItemReached && indexPath.row == dataArray!.hits.count - 1 {`

Comment: What is the `self.launchReload` method?

Comment: The `launchReload` method is your own method to gather data that will fill your dataArray. Could be a call to a web service, some local json parsing, ..

Comment: Not working for me. reloadData causes this to be triggered multiple times.

Comment: yes, please add a check on lastItem so lauchReload isn't called. I'm updating the answer

Comment: @shinyuX not working for me, "if" always false...but if  (lastItemReached && indexPath.row == [self.dataArray count] - 1) true, WHY?

Answer (score 78):

## Swift

**Method 1: Did scroll to bottom**

Here is the Swift version of [Pedro Romão's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22385922/3681880). When the user stops scrolling it checks if it has reached the bottom.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    // UITableView only moves in one direction, y axis
    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height

    // Change 10.0 to adjust the distance from bottom
    if maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 10.0 {
        self.loadMore()
    }
}
```

**Method 2: Reached last row**

And here is the Swift version of [shinyuX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20269614/3681880). It checks if the user has reached the last row.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // set up cell
    // ...

    // Check if the last row number is the same as the last current data element
    if indexPath.row == self.dataArray.count - 1 {
        self.loadMore()
    }

}
```

## Example of a `loadMore()` method

I set up these three class variables for fetching batches of data.

```
// number of items to be fetched each time (i.e., database LIMIT)
let itemsPerBatch = 50

// Where to start fetching items (database OFFSET)
var offset = 0

// a flag for when all database items have already been loaded
var reachedEndOfItems = false
```

This is the function to load more items from the database into the table view.

```
func loadMore() {

    // don't bother doing another db query if already have everything
    guard !self.reachedEndOfItems else {
        return
    }

    // query the db on a background thread
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        // determine the range of data items to fetch
        var thisBatchOfItems: [MyObjects]?
        let start = self.offset
        let end = self.offset + self.itemsPerBatch

        // query the database
        do {
            // SQLite.swift wrapper
            thisBatchOfItems = try MyDataHelper.findRange(start..<end)
        } catch _ {
            print("query failed")
        }

        // update UITableView with new batch of items on main thread after query finishes
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let newItems = thisBatchOfItems {

                // append the new items to the data source for the table view
                self.myObjectArray.appendContentsOf(newItems)

                // reload the table view
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                // check if this was the last of the data
                if newItems.count < self.itemsPerBatch {
                    self.reachedEndOfItems = true
                    print("reached end of data. Batch count: \(newItems.count)")
                }

                // reset the offset for the next data query
                self.offset += self.itemsPerBatch
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38):

Better to use `willDisplayCell` method to check if which cell will be loaded.
 Once we get the current `indexPath.row` is last we can load more cells.
 This will load more cells on scrolling down.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
       willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell    
       forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // check if indexPath.row is last row
    // Perform operation to load new Cell's.
}
```

Comment: it's not any better since reloadData will call this method again right ?

Comment: Yes this will work for sections, indexPath will give you row & section both.

Answer (score 32):

### Details

- Swift 5.1, Xcode 11.2.1

### Solution

> Worked with UIScrollView / UICollectionView / UITableView

```
import UIKit

class LoadMoreActivityIndicator {

    private let spacingFromLastCell: CGFloat
    private let spacingFromLastCellWhenLoadMoreActionStart: CGFloat
    private weak var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView?
    private weak var scrollView: UIScrollView?

    private var defaultY: CGFloat {
        guard let height = scrollView?.contentSize.height else { return 0.0 }
        return height + spacingFromLastCell
    }

    deinit { activityIndicatorView?.removeFromSuperview() }

    init (scrollView: UIScrollView, spacingFromLastCell: CGFloat, spacingFromLastCellWhenLoadMoreActionStart: CGFloat) {
        self.scrollView = scrollView
        self.spacingFromLastCell = spacingFromLastCell
        self.spacingFromLastCellWhenLoadMoreActionStart = spacingFromLastCellWhenLoadMoreActionStart
        let size:CGFloat = 40
        let frame = CGRect(x: (scrollView.frame.width-size)/2, y: scrollView.contentSize.height + spacingFromLastCell, width: size, height: size)
        let activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: frame)
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *)
        {
            activityIndicatorView.color = .label
        }
        else
        {
            activityIndicatorView.color = .black
        }
        activityIndicatorView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
        activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = true
        scrollView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
        self.activityIndicatorView = activityIndicatorView
    }

    private var isHidden: Bool {
        guard let scrollView = scrollView else { return true }
        return scrollView.contentSize.height < scrollView.frame.size.height
    }

    func start(closure: (() -> Void)?) {
        guard let scrollView = scrollView, let activityIndicatorView = activityIndicatorView else { return }
        let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        activityIndicatorView.isHidden = isHidden
        if !isHidden && offsetY >= 0 {
            let contentDelta = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
            let offsetDelta = offsetY - contentDelta
            
            let newY = defaultY-offsetDelta
            if newY < scrollView.frame.height {
                activityIndicatorView.frame.origin.y = newY
            } else {
                if activityIndicatorView.frame.origin.y != defaultY {
                    activityIndicatorView.frame.origin.y = defaultY
                }
            }

            if !activityIndicatorView.isAnimating {
                if offsetY > contentDelta && offsetDelta >= spacingFromLastCellWhenLoadMoreActionStart && !activityIndicatorView.isAnimating {
                    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
                    closure?()
                }
            }

            if scrollView.isDecelerating {
                if activityIndicatorView.isAnimating && scrollView.contentInset.bottom == 0 {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { [weak self] in
                        if let bottom = self?.spacingFromLastCellWhenLoadMoreActionStart {
                            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: bottom, right: 0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func stop(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        guard let scrollView = scrollView , let activityIndicatorView = activityIndicatorView else { return }
        let contentDelta = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
        let offsetDelta = scrollView.contentOffset.y - contentDelta
        if offsetDelta >= 0 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            }) { _ in completion?() }
        } else {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            completion?()
        }
        activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

### Usage

**init**

```
activityIndicator = LoadMoreActivityIndicator(scrollView: tableView, spacingFromLastCell: 10, spacingFromLastCellWhenLoadMoreActionStart: 60)
```

**handling**

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        activityIndicator.start {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
                sleep(3)
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.activityIndicator.stop()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Full Sample

> Do not forget to paste the solution code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    fileprivate var activityIndicator: LoadMoreActivityIndicator!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: view.frame)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        activityIndicator = LoadMoreActivityIndicator(scrollView: tableView, spacingFromLastCell: 10, spacingFromLastCellWhenLoadMoreActionStart: 60)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        activityIndicator.start {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
                for i in 0..<3 {
                    print("!!!!!!!!! \(i)")
                    sleep(1)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.activityIndicator.stop()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Works perfect. But I have a header in my tableview, after drag to load more, the header will go under the nav bar.. UIEdgeInsetsMake in loadMoreActionFinshed should be set to (62, 0, 0, 0) considering 66 = navbar.height + 22

Comment: It should work in CollectionView when you scroll vertically.

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk no problem, I will do it and share here for others

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk activityIndicator.start.. Where is the start function?

Comment: @pragmus look at full sample: `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`

Comment: Yes Great now it's working fine. Facing one problem just first time when data is loaded indicator frame not set to bottom it jumps. any solution for this ? Thanks for help.

Comment: @YogeshPatel I suppose you are reloading table view cells views and try to stop load more view at the same time. Try to reload table view cells and then stop activity indicator.

Comment: i have one last question for you. scrollViewDidScroll is a UIScrollViewDelegate or UITableViewDelegate ? Can you please summaries this thanks @VasilyBodnarchuk

Comment: @YogeshPatel `scrollViewDidScroll` is a part of `UIScrollViewDelegate` but `UITableViewDelegate : UIScrollViewDelegate`

Answer (score 19):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
    NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
    if ((indexPath.section == lastSectionIndex) && (indexPath.row == lastRowIndex)) {
        // This is the last cell
        [self loadMore];
    }
}
```

If you are using Core Data and `NSFetchedResultsController`, then `loadMore` could look like the following:

```
// Load more
- (void)loadMore {
    [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setFetchLimit:newFetchLimit];
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"cache name"];
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this but I am using an array of results and not sqlite, was wondering how I would go about adding more into the current NSMutableArray I have and then reloading the data, because otherwise the data gets overwritten... I tried this [names addObjectsFromArray: [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"name"]]; but it is not working... here is a link to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446780/how-to-add-more-data-when-scrolling-without-erasing-previous-data-in-the-array?noredirect=1#comment35939431_23446780

Comment: What's the point to refetch data again each time you get new data? If frc is configured correctly, single fetch is enough, it will update accordingly as needed. Fetching it everytime, assuming frc's fetch request is configured to a main thread context will block main thread as it hits the disk, that's totally not good for user experience when user wants new data.

Comment: The first half of this was very helpful for me, thanks. (Not using FetchedResultsVC)

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii is correct. One of the key features of the NSFetchedResultsController is that it computes the paging data so that you get virtual scrolling for free when you connect it up to a UITableView. Implementing such a loadMore function should only be necessary if you are actually filling your CoreData store with more data, in which case there is no need to do another performFetch if your NSFetchedResultsController is configured correctly.

Comment: Same issues as other answers. reloadData causes this to occur multiple times.

Answer (score 17):

### Details

- Swift 5.1, Xcode 11.3.1

### Solution

> Generic UITableView Extension For Loadmore.

add this UITableView + Extension in your new file

```
extension UITableView {

func indicatorView() -> UIActivityIndicatorView{
    var activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    if self.tableFooterView == nil {
        let indicatorFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: 80)
        activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: indicatorFrame)
        activityIndicatorView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
        
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            activityIndicatorView.style = .large
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            activityIndicatorView.style = .whiteLarge
        }
        
        activityIndicatorView.color = .systemPink
        activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = true

        self.tableFooterView = activityIndicatorView
        return activityIndicatorView
    }
    else {
        return activityIndicatorView
    }
}

func addLoading(_ indexPath:IndexPath, closure: @escaping (() -> Void)){
    indicatorView().startAnimating()
    if let lastVisibleIndexPath = self.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last {
        if indexPath == lastVisibleIndexPath && indexPath.row == self.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1 {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                closure()
            }
        }
    }
}

func stopLoading() {
    if self.tableFooterView != nil {
        self.indicatorView().stopAnimating()
        self.tableFooterView = nil
    }
    else {
        self.tableFooterView = nil
    }
} 
}
```

Now, just add following line of code in UITableViewDelegate Method willDisplay Cell in your ViewController and make sure tableView.delegate = self

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // need to pass your indexpath then it showing your indicator at bottom 
    tableView.addLoading(indexPath) {
        // add your code here
        // append Your array and reload your tableview
        tableView.stopLoading() // stop your indicator
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]

That's it.. Hope this helpful. Thank You

Comment: Things to consider. Just add 'tableFooterView = nil' inside in the stoploading func otherwise the indicator spinning will not stop animating.

Also there is property in the activityIndicator 'hidesWhenStopped' so you don't need to manually set hidden true/false the indicator. But overall it looks great :)

Comment: Just a couple of things. 
1) "addLoading" is being called every time a cell is about to be displayed. indicatorView shouldn't start the animation until lastVisibleIndexPath, etc is checked.
2) "addLoading" uses indicatorView, which is created every time with UIActivityIndicatorView(). If tableViewFooter is nil, you already create it from there. If tableViewFooter is not nil, you can check if that's actually the UIActivityIndicatorView, instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 12):

I have implemented one solution that i found in stackoverflow, and it works fine, but i think the shinyuX's solution it's very easy to implement and works fine for my propose.
If someone wants a different solution can use this one below.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

   // UITableView only moves in one direction, y axis
    CGFloat currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;

    //NSInteger result = maximumOffset - currentOffset;

    // Change 10.0 to adjust the distance from bottom
    if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 10.0) {
        [self loadOneMorePage];
        //[self methodThatAddsDataAndReloadsTableView];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there are different scenarios for view presentation, in my case yours solution worked, I needed something like this

Comment: If the user flings hard, i.e. 1.5 screens high, the bottom can be reached without refreshed being triggered.

Comment: but it scroll the list to top

Answer (score 6):

Use limit and offset in your queries and fill your tableview with that content. When the user scrolls down, load the next offset.

Implement the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method in your `UITableViewDelegate` and check to see if it's the last row

Answer (score 5):

One more option to use (**Swift 3** and iOS 10+):

```
class DocumentEventsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching {

     var currentPage: Int = 1
     let pageSize: Int = 10 // num of items in one page

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         self.tableView.prefetchDataSource = self
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
         let upcomingRows = indexPaths.map { $0.row }

         if let maxIndex = upcomingRows.max() {

            let nextPage: Int = Int(ceil(Double(maxIndex) / Double(pageSize))) + 1

            if nextPage > currentPage {
                 // Your function, which attempts to load respective page from the local database
                 loadLocalData(page: nextPage)

                 // Your function, which makes a network request to fetch the respective page of data from the network
                 startLoadingDataFromNetwork(page: nextPage) 

                 currentPage = nextPage
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

For rather small pages (~ 10 items) you might want to manually add data for pages 1 and 2 because nextPage might be somewhere about 1-2 until the table has a few items to be scrolled well. But it will work great for all next pages.

Comment: This does work only for read-only data. Doesn't work If you have functionality like delete some row and load more as pageSize is been fixed here and can't load more even If there is more data after you update your source.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (news.count == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return news.count +  1 ;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    @try {

        uint position = (uint) (indexPath.row);
        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
        NSUInteger count = [news count];

        //show Load More
        if (row == count) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

            static NSString *LoadMoreId = @"LoadMore";
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LoadMoreId];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                        initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                      reuseIdentifier:LoadMoreId];
            }
            if (!hasMoreLoad) {
                cell.hidden = true;
            } else {

                cell.textLabel.text = @"Load more items...";
                cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
                NSLog(@"Load more");
                if (!isMoreLoaded) {
                    isMoreLoaded = true;
                    [self performSelector:@selector(loadMoreNews) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
                }
            }

            return cell;

        } else {
            NewsRow *cell = nil;

            NewsObject *newsObject = news[position];
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewsRow";
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) {
                // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
                NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
                // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
                cell = topLevelObjects[0];
                // Configure the cell...

            }

            cell.title.text = newsObject.title;             
            return cell;
        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception occurred: %@, %@", exception, [exception userInfo]);
    }
    return nil;
}
```

very good explanation on this post.

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/10/02/dynamically-loading-new-rows-into-a-table.html

simple you have to add last row and hide it and when table row hit last row than show the row and load more items.

Answer (score 1):

you should check ios UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mytableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mytableview.prefetchDataSource = self
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        print("prefetchdRowsAtIndexpath \(indexPaths)")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cancelPrefetchingForRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        print("cancelPrefetchingForRowsAtIndexpath \(indexPaths)")
    }


}
```

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching
  https://andreygordeev.com/2017/02/20/uitableview-prefetching/

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTHkcf9gSRw) seems like a great tutorial!

Starter/Complete project: https://github.com/RobCanton/Swift-Infinite-Scrolling-Example

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var tableView:UITableView!

    var fetchingMore = false
    var items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        initTableView()
    }

    func initTableView() {
        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableCell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Item \(items[indexPath.row])"
            return cell
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

        if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.height * 4 {
            if !fetchingMore {
                beginBatchFetch()
            }
        }
    }

    func beginBatchFetch() {
        fetchingMore = true
        print("Call API here..")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.50, execute: {
            print("Consider this as API response.")
            let newItems = (self.items.count...self.items.count + 12).map { index in index }
            self.items.append(contentsOf: newItems)
            self.fetchingMore = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for loading from an API, It works for me, Xcode**10** , swift **4.2** :

**1- create New Swift file and do like this:**

```
//
//  apiTVCController.swift
//  ApiTestingTableView
//
//  Created by Hooma7n on 4/7/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Hooma7n. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import Alamofire

class apiget {

    var tableData : [Datum] = []
    var loadin : [Datum] = []
    var testfortotal : Int?


    func getfromapi(completionHandler : ((_ isSucess : Bool) -> Void)?) {
        let url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1"
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON(completionHandler : { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) else {return}
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    guard let result = try? decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData) else {return}
                    self.tableData = result.data ?? []
                    self.testfortotal = result.total ?? 0
                    completionHandler?(true)

                //                    print(result)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            })
    }

    var pagecounter : Int = 2


    func loadmore(completionHandler : ((_ isSucess : Bool) -> Void)?){

        let url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=\(pagecounter)"
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON(completionHandler : { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) else {return}
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    guard let myresult = try? decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData) else {return}
                    self.loadin = myresult.data ?? []
                    self.tableData.append(contentsOf: myresult.data ?? [])
                    completionHandler?(true)
                    print(self.pagecounter)
                    self.pagecounter += 1

                //                    print(myresult)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            })

    }

}

extension apiget {

    struct Welcome: Codable {
        let page, perPage, total, totalPages: Int?
        var data: [Datum]?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case page
            case perPage = "per_page"
            case total
            case totalPages = "total_pages"
            case data
        }
    }

    struct Datum: Codable {
        let id: Int?
        let firstName, lastName: String?
        let avatar: String?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case id
            case firstName = "first_name"
            case lastName = "last_name"
            case avatar
        }
    }


}
```

**2- in Your ViewController file (tableView Controller) :**

```
//
//  apiTVC.swift
//  ApiTestingTableView
//
//  Created by Hooma7n on 4/7/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Hooma7n. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Alamofire

class apiTVC: UITableViewController {

    var datamodel = apiget()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        datamodel.getfromapi(completionHandler: {finish in
            if finish {self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        })

    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return datamodel.tableData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! apiTableViewCell
        cell.firstNameLabel.text = datamodel.tableData[indexPath.row].firstName
        cell.lastNameLabel.text = datamodel.tableData[indexPath.row].lastName
        cell.dateLabel.text = "\(datamodel.tableData[indexPath.row].id ?? 0)"
        cell.profileImageView.loadImage(fromURL: datamodel.tableData[indexPath.row].avatar ?? "")

        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let lastElement = datamodel.tableData.count - 1
        let total = datamodel.testfortotal ?? 12
        if indexPath.row == lastElement && datamodel.tableData.count < total{

            datamodel.loadmore(completionHandler: {finish in
                if finish {

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }})
        }
    }
}
```

if using tableView in Your viewController set **delegate**,**datasource** self in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanna share this approach:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [[YourTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]);
    [self estimatedTotalData];
}

- (void)estimatedTotalData
{
    long currentRow = ((NSIndexPath *)[[YourTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row;

    long estimateDataCount = 25;

    while (currentRow > estimateDataCount)
    {
        estimateDataCount+=25;
    }

    dataLimit = estimateDataCount;

    if (dataLimit == currentRow+1)
    {
        dataLimit+=25;
    }

    NSLog(@"dataLimit :%ld", dataLimit);

    [self requestForData];

    // this answers the question..
    //
    if(YourDataSource.count-1 == currentRow)
    {
        NSLog(@"LAST ROW"); //loadMore data
    }
}
```

`NSLog(...);` output would be something like:

```
<NSIndexPath: 0xc0000000002e0016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 92}
dataLimit :100
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000298016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 83}
dataLimit :100
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000278016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 79}
dataLimit :100
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000238016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 71}
dataLimit :75
<NSIndexPath: 0xc0000000001d8016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 59}
dataLimit :75
<NSIndexPath: 0xc0000000001c0016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 56}
dataLimit :75
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000138016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 39}
dataLimit :50
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000120016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 36}
dataLimit :50
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000008016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
dataLimit :25
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000008016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
dataLimit :25
```

This is good for displaying data stored locally.
Initially I declare the dataLimit to 25, that means uitableview will have 0-24 (initially).

If the user scrolled to the bottom and the last cell is visible `dataLimit` will be added with 25...

Note: This is more like a UITableView data paging, :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSInteger sectionsAmount = [tableView numberOfSections];
NSInteger rowsAmount = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
if ([indexPath section] == sectionsAmount - 1 && [indexPath row] == rowsAmount - 1) {
    //get last row
    if (!isSearchActive && !isFilterSearchActive) {
        if (totalRecords % 8 == 0) {
            int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {


            [yourTableView beginUpdates];
            [yourTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            [yourTableView endUpdates];
            });
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: after displaying last row , insert rows i.e  beginUpdates..and use some delay for get no crash.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is to add cell at the bottom of your table, and this cell will hold indicator.

In swift you need to add this:

1. Create new cell of type cellLoading this will hold the indicator. Look at the code below
2. Look at the num of rows and add 1 to it (This is for loading cell).
3. you need to check in the rawAtIndex if idexPath.row == yourArray.count then return Loading cell.

look at code below:

```
import UIKit

class LoadingCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!


}
```

For table view  : 
  numOfRows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  yourArray.count + 1
}
```

cellForRawAt indexPath:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == users.count  {
        // need to change
        let loading = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("LoadingCell", owner: LoadingCell.self , options: nil)?.first as! LoadingCell
        return loading

    }

    let yourCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellCustomizing", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    return yourCell

}
```

If you notice that my loading cell is created from a nib file. [This videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAWO9rldyUE) will explain what I did.

Answer (score 0):

```
let threshold = 100.0 // threshold from bottom of tableView
var isLoadingMore = false // flag


func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;

    if !isLoadingMore && (maximumOffset - contentOffset <= threshold) {
        // Get more data - API call
        self.isLoadingMore = true

        // Update UI
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            tableView.reloadData()
            self.isLoadingMore = false
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is sample code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:ShowComplainCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as! ShowComplainCell

    let item  = self.dataArray[indexPath.row] as! ComplainListItem;

    let indexPathArray = NSArray(array: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!)
    let vIndexPath = indexPathArray.lastObject as! NSIndexPath

    let lastItemReached = item.isEqual(self.dataArray.lastObject);

    if (lastItemReached && vIndexPath.row == (self.dataArray.count - 1))
       {

        self.loadData()
       }
    


    return cell
    
}
```

indexPathArray: is visible rows.

vIndexPath:is visible last indexpath

load data

```
 func loadData(){

       if(isReloadTable){
       let HUD = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
       let manager :AFHTTPSessionManager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
     
       
           var param = NSDictionary()
           param = [
               "category":cat_id,
               "smart_user_id": USERDEF.value(forKey: "user_id") as! String,
               "page":page,
               "phone":phone! as String
               
           ] as [String : Any] as NSDictionary
           print("param1 = \(param)")

           manager.get("lists.php?", parameters: param, progress: nil, success: { (task:URLSessionDataTask, responseObject: Any) in
               
     
                       let adsArray =  dic["results"] as! NSArray;
                       for item in adsArray {
                           let item  = ComplainListItem(dictionary: item as! NSDictionary )
                           self.dataArray.add(item)
                       }
                   
                       self.view.addSubview(self.cityTableView)
                       self.cityTableView.reloadData()
                   
                   if(adsArray.count==10){
                       self.cityTableView.reloadData()
                       self.isReloadTable = true
                       self.page+=1
                   }else if(adsArray.count<10){
                       self.cityTableView.reloadData()
                       self.isReloadTable = false
               }
               
               HUD.hide(animated:true)
               
           }) { (operation,error) -> Void in
               print("error = \(error)")
               HUD.hide(animated:true)
           }
       }
        
   }
```

check your dataArray count which is myadsarray check to equal your data limit. then if dataArray count equal next page is called if not equal which is less then 10, all data is showed or finished.