# How to add more data when scrolling without erasing previous data in the array?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am having issues trying to allow a user to scroll to the bottom and if they get to the end I want to load more rows by calling my server. I am using AFNetworking for the calls, and in the complete callback I reload the data, however, when it calls more data it erases previous I want it to add more.

Here is my current code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row + 50 > [self.userIds count]) //self.array is the array of items you are displaying
    {

        [self getMoreFollowing];
        //If it is the last cell, Add items to your array here & update the table view
    }
}

-(void)getMoreFollowing {

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    // NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"userId": userProfileId, @"count": @(count)};
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    //manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]; // if response JSON format
    [manager GET:@"http://example.com/users"
      parameters:@{ @"userId": userProfileId,
                    @"count": @(count)}
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
             NSLog(@"Data saved");

             //set other arrays for passing data
             [userIds addObjectsFromArray: [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"_id"]];
             [names addObjectsFromArray: [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"name"]];

             count = [userIds count];
             [self.tableView reloadData];

         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

         }];

}
```

I have tried adding it

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *userIds;
```

UPDATE:
There is no error, but the tables are not even created, it stays blank, if I set userIds = to that and the others as well then it overwrites it with the call... what needs to happen?

Comment: You created `userIds` as a normal (immutable) `NSArray`, not a mutable one.

Comment: How huh it says Mutable? what needs to be different?

Comment: The property is declared as mutable, but wherever you're setting it, you're setting it to an immutable array. You need to show us where that is.

Comment: check the "names" array

Comment: Look at the edit, but the issue is now the tables are not even created, it stays blank, if I set userIds = to that and the others as well then it overwrites it with the call... what needs to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a second set of NSMutable Arrays and just concatenated the two like so:

```
[userIdsArray addObjectsFromArray:userIds];
```

Then called it like so:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row + 50 > [userIdsArray count]) //self.array is the array of items you are displaying
    {
        [self getFollowers];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create mutable copy of your array and insert object instead of adding then set your array.

```
[mutableCopyOfYourArray insertObject:(id) atIndex:(NSUInteger)];
yourArray = mutableCopyOfYourArray;
```

Inserting object at index will shift the object originally occupying the index by 1 and insert what you want there. I doubt if that's what you want to do. You just have to use addObject to insert item at the end of the array and reload table data

```
[mutableCopyofYourArray addObject:yourNewitem];
yourArray=mutableCopyofYourArray;  
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

If you want to add items at the top, then you use the insertObject atIndex and set the index to 0

Comment: Look at the exception.

Comment: i was fixing my answer.

Comment: What index would I be adding in this?

Comment: if you want to add new items on top of all you can insert to index 0. if you want to add end of the line you can put atIndex:yourArrayCount-1

Comment: Isn't my array already mutable shouldn't I be able to add right to it though? I tried this and it still ends up blank...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)getMoreFollowing {

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
// NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"userId": userProfileId, @"count": @(count)};
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
//manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]; // if response JSON format
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/users"
  parameters:@{ @"userId": userProfileId,
                @"count": @(count)}
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
         NSLog(@"Data saved");

         //set other arrays for passing data
         [userIds addObjectsFromArray: [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"_id"]];
         [names addObjectsFromArray: [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"name"]];



     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];

   count = [userIds count];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Comment: That will cause an async issue no?

Comment: @Lion789 Dude , I brought the reloadData method outside.  If the problems is coming from how you add your new data to your existing data and your response data is an array of dictionaries. I suggest you iterate through that array and use the orthodox objectforkey to get the values individually and add it to your existing array