# Load table at bottom instead of top

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to load the table at the bottom of the scrolling view instead of the top. I used this code but it's loading the table at the top.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    float bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
        if ((isloading = true)) {
            pageno= pageno+1;
            [self fetchdata];
            [self.tableview reloadData];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add data at the end in your data array

Comment: Show the code for fetch data

Comment: Here no need to use `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` method. Search answer for load more concept in `UITableView` will your best match. Like - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269474/uitableview-load-more-when-scrolling-to-bottom-like-facebook-application

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` inherit from `UIScrollView`. You can use the property `contentSize` to get the height of the content, then you can use

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

or, if you know which is your last row

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/reference/uitableview_class/index.html)