# Best way to create IOS "table" and programmatically add cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

New IOS developer and looking for the best way to create a`UITableView` that I can programmatically add cells to.

The idea is that when I load the app I will retrieve a list of names with `UIImages`. I want to programmatically add these names as cells stacked horizontally with a text value. Image below is exactly what I'm looking for:

[image]

In this example I retrieve the background images with the names "Texas A&M Football", "People of Walmart", etc.

I have tried using`UITableView` and`UITableViewCells` but not sure how to programmatically add them in the implementation file.

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You should read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS". It covers how to do everything in both code and through Interface Builder.

Comment: Have you already taken a look at this post? It looks like it's something similar as that what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269474/uitableview-load-more-when-scrolling-to-bottom-like-facebook-application

Comment: Thanks @OutOfBounds, this looks exactly like what I'm looking for!