# How to use cellWillDisplay/scrollViewDidScroll to update API fetch data? Swift

Tags: swift, api, tableview, scrollview

I'm new to Swift development,
I want to fetch data from API, and found some problems,
I want to fetch 20 data only in my table view, and when I scroll to the bottom I can fetch another 20 data so on...

[API here](https://data.taipei/opendata/datalist/apiAccess?scope=resourceAquire&rid=f18de02f-b6c9-47c0-8cda-50efad621c14)

My problem here is this API directly response 220 data at once,
I don't know how to separate into 20 and re-fetch

I have try some tutorial using cellWillDisplay and scrollViewDidScroll,
but I can barely understand since they all use fixed data,
Do someone know how to solve this?

here's my code, Model

```
func getBotanicalResults(pagination: Bool = false, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[ResultsDetail], BotanicalError>) -> Void) {
    let urlString = "https://data.taipei/opendata/datalist/apiAccess?scope=resourceAquire&rid=f18de02f-b6c9-47c0-8cda-50efad621c14"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        completionHandler(.failure(.invalidURL))
        return
    }
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let jsonData = data else {
            completionHandler(.failure(.noDataAvailable))
            return
        }
        do {
            let botanicalResponse = try decoder.decode(BotanicalMain.self, from: jsonData)
            let botanicalResults = botanicalResponse.result.results
            print("success getting results!")
            completionHandler(.success(botanicalResults))
        } catch {
            completionHandler(.failure(.canNotProcessData))
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

here's my code, fetchData()

```
func fetchData() {
    model.getBotanicalResults(pagination: false) { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case .success(let botanicals):
            self?.listOfBotanical = botanicals
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here's my code, cellForRowAt

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PropertyKeys.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? BotanicalCell else {
        fatalError("Fail to dequeue BotanicalCell")
    }
    
    let botanical = listOfBotanical[indexPath.row]
    cell.displayDetails(botanical)
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: "to fetch 20 data"  You mean, 20 records?  No person can count data.

Comment: So where is your cellWillDisplay or scrollViewDidScroll thing?

Comment: Have you looked at prefetchDataSource: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1771763-prefetchdatasource

Comment: @ElTomato yes, 20 records, I just see their is so many way for pagination, but not sure whether they can fit my code, but after using limit & offset parameter in the API, I can just limit my data fetching in 20 and load another 20 after I scroll to the bottom, all those are wrote in tableView datasource cellForRowAt!

Answer (score 0):

The API you mentioned should have limit, offset, etc parameters. If the api does not have such arguments, you can not have those pagination logic. If api supports that you can check the sample project below. The main page has a pagination logic uses what you want to create.

[sampleproject](https://github.com/erkutbas/MarvelCodeCase)

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look, fantastic app by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Swift!

**First: API parameter queries**

You have this api:

```
https://data.taipei/opendata/datalist/apiAccess?scope=resourceAquire&rid=f18de02f-b6c9-47c0-8cda-50efad621c14
```

It supports `limit` and `offset` parameter query. So, how to add them?
You should add them after `?`

> P.S: `limit` is the number of records and `offset` is the number of skipped records.

For example:
This will return 1 record and starting from the beginning.

```
https://data.taipei/opendata/datalist/apiAccess?scope=resourceAquire&rid=f18de02f-b6c9-47c0-8cda-50efad621c14&limit=1&offset=0
```

And, This will return 20 record and starting from the beginning (Same as: Page 1).

```
https://data.taipei/opendata/datalist/apiAccess?scope=resourceAquire&rid=f18de02f-b6c9-47c0-8cda-50efad621c14&limit=20&offset=0
```

Finally, This will return 20 record and starting from the next 20 records (Same as: Page 2).

```
https://data.taipei/opendata/datalist/apiAccess?scope=resourceAquire&rid=f18de02f-b6c9-47c0-8cda-50efad621c14&limit=20&offset=20
```

**Second: Load more rows when user reach the end of table view:**

> [Load more technique to allow table view paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269474/uitableview-load-more-when-scrolling-to-bottom-like-facebook-application)

Comment: How do you know all this stuff?  Do you work for data.taipei?

Comment: @ElTomato No, it is straightforward because I have experience :)

Comment: @HamadFuad thanks for the suggestion! I have tried that on postman before and it does have limit and offset parameter.

Comment: I'm just too dumb to solve how to fetch another 20 data, I think load more need to have offset parameter, and after the cell is scroll to the last cell, I need to call loadMore() and append the data into my previous array, I just solve it XD

Comment: but need to add some indicator to show loading, I think loadMore() behavior is faster than I think :)