# iOS dynamically load new cell to the bottom of a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm working on an iOS project where I want to dynamically add more cell to the bottom of the tableview once the user reaches the bottom.  I currently have this working by calling a method that fetches more data that is added to the array that I'm using to hold my cells. When I'm done adding the objects to the array I call [tableView reloadData].  This works, but it doesn't visually load the cell until the tableview stops scrolling.

I also tried using [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: inSection:withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone].  But I was getting very strange behavior where random cell would disappear and not show back up until I scrolled that section of the tableView off screen and then back to that area.

Is there a way to get the tableView to reload even if the tableView is still in mid scroll when the [tableView reloadDate] is called?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137943/how-to-know-when-uitableview-did-scroll-to-bottom ?

Comment: No I have seen that one yet, but I think it is exactly what I was looking for.  I'll try it out.  Thank you!

Comment: That matches my experience. The table contents is not updated until the talbe stops scrolling. I have seen that in other apps too. Therfore I thought that this is 'as is'. If there is any trick to change that, I'd be greateful too.

Comment: I Just added the - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView { delegate call from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137943/how-to-know-when-uitableview-did-scroll-to-bottom  .  I changed the called to fetch more cell right after the NSLog(@"load more rows");.   It works perfectly now!   Thanks JiaYow!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out: [How to know when UITableView did scroll to bottom in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137943/how-to-know-when-uitableview-did-scroll-to-bottom)
neoneye's answer about - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView { was exactly what I was looking for.  I moved the method call to fetch more cell right after the NSLog(@"load more rows");

Thank you JiaYow for steering me in the right direction!