# Amount of scrolling in scrollViewWillBeginDragging

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Is there any way to find how much UITableView has been scrolled in any direction ? I am interested in amount not in direction.

Comment: Can you please provide more info. Like in which sense you require this, what is the actual requirement, what are the ways you have tried?

Comment: I am getting data from the server and displaying that data into my tableviewcell. but i want to load only 10 records at a time. for this purpose i am using limit-offset thing.  but i'm not very much clear how to do this in ios. I am setting those limit-offset in NSUrl.

Comment: Similar questions: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137943/how-to-know-when-uitableview-did-scroll-to-bottom-in-iphone 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786774/ios-dynamically-load-new-cell-to-the-bottom-of-a-tableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily grab the exact offset of the table view by looking at its contentOffset property. For the vertical scroll, look at:

```
tableView.contentOffset.y;
```

and with this you can take your tableview to any particular location

```
[theTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:savedScrollPosition inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];                        
CGPoint point = theTableView.contentOffset;
point .y -= theTableView.rowHeight;
theTableView.contentOffset = point;
```

for you requirement of load more cells after 10 you can use this logic

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = aScrollView.bounds;
    CGSize size = aScrollView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = aScrollView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;
    // NSLog(@"offset: %f", offset.y);   
    // NSLog(@"content.height: %f", size.height);   
    // NSLog(@"bounds.height: %f", bounds.size.height);   
    // NSLog(@"inset.top: %f", inset.top);   
    // NSLog(@"inset.bottom: %f", inset.bottom);   
    // NSLog(@"pos: %f of %f", y, h);

    float reload_distance = 10;
    if(y > h + reload_distance) {
        NSLog(@"load more rows");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me.
 Just one little help. As i load new data,size of tableView will increase. So how can i adjust the height accordingly ? So data doesn't get loaded if not required.

Comment: you need to set tableview frame according to it's content height that might give you the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to measure the `contentOffset` of the `UITableView` when dragging begins and when it ends. Take a difference between the two, it will give you the amount of change from initial to final position.

```
CGPoint oldOffset;
CGPoint newOffset;

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      oldOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
      newOffset = *targetContentOffset;
      CGPoint diff = {newOffset.x - oldOffset.x, newOffset.y - oldOffset.y};

      // Where diff.x => amount of change in x-coord of offset
      // diff.y => amount of change in y coord of offset
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can find it using below syntax...

```
NSLog(@"scrolled:%f",yourtableview.contentOffset.y);//y for vertical, x for horizontal
```