# IOS Issue Getting Index Path Row at Specific Point

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a view controller that contains a navigation bar, a table view and a tool bar.  I included the UITableViewDelegate in the view controller, and correctly assigned the table's data source and delegate to the view controller through the storyboard.  The table view loads its data from a remote database, once the table scrolls to the last cell more data is loaded into the table.  I achieved this by using the scrollViewDidScroll and indexPathForRowAtPoint methods as outlined in the following post: [How to know when UITableView did scroll to bottom in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137943/how-to-know-when-uitableview-did-scroll-to-bottom-in-iphone).  However, when I run the app and scroll through the table the only index path returned by indexPathForRowAtPoint is the one that was located at the specified point at the time of table load.  Here is the code and the output I get when I scroll:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint bottomPoint = CGPointMake(160, 430);
    CGPoint topPoint = CGPointMake(160, 10);

    NSLog(@"%d", [[_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:bottomPoint] row]);

}
```

Every time I scroll the following is outputted:

```
2013-06-08 00:56:45.006 Coffee[24493:907] 3
2013-06-08 00:56:45.012 Coffee[24493:907] 3
2013-06-08 00:56:45.040 Coffee[24493:907] 3
2013-06-08 00:56:45.069 Coffee[24493:907] 3
2013-06-08 00:56:45.088 Coffee[24493:907] 3
2013-06-08 00:56:45.105 Coffee[24493:907] 3
2013-06-08 00:56:45.135 Coffee[24493:907] 3
2013-06-08 00:56:45.144 Coffee[24493:907] 3
2013-06-08 00:56:45.173 Coffee[24493:907] 3
2013-06-08 00:56:45.180 Coffee[24493:907] 3
```

Where 3 is the indexPath.row of the cell the bottom point is on when the controller loads.  What am I doing wrong and why is this happening?  Does it have anything to do with the fact that the UITableView is located inside a parent view controller?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`bottomPoint` is looking for a location inside your `scrollView`.  Your `scrollView` contains a table, and all the cells are in the SAME PLACE all the time, relative to your `scrollView`.  That is why you always get the same cell at that point.

When you scroll, the cells don't move in the `scrollView`, the `scrollView` "moves" relative to its parent.  This is done by having its contentOffset changed.

If you add your `scrollView`'s y content offset to your `bottomPoint`, you'll get the point that you are probably really looking for in your `scrollView`.

like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint bottomPoint = CGPointMake(160, 430) - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGPoint topPoint = CGPointMake(160, 10);

    NSLog(@"%d", [[_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:bottomPoint] row]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! Didn't realize that that's how IOS did it.  @HalR

Comment: I struggled with it a bunch when I was starting on iOS.  I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the Apple's Documentation, the Method `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` is refer to a point in the local coordinate system of the receiver (**the table view's bounds**), **BUT NO** the table view's frame. As the bottomPoint you set is in the table view's frame coordinate system, you will not get the right `indexPath`. HalR's answer gives the bottomPoint in the table view's bounds coordinate system.

`indexPathForRowAtPoint:`

Returns an index path identifying the row and section at the given point.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
```

**Parameters**
*point:*
  a point in the local coordinate system of the receiver (the table view's bounds).

**Return Value**
An *index path* representing the row and section associated with point or `nil` if the point is out of the bounds of any row.

FYI [different between Frame and Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/ios-programming-frame-bounds-and-center)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the class to implement the feature.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let flagView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 20.0))

        flagView.backgroundColor = .blue

        self.view.addSubview(flagView)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell number: \(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        let currentPoint = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - 100, y: 100.0 + scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        print(" current index:  \(String(describing: tableView.indexPathForRow(at: currentPoint)?.row))")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
let bottomPoint = CGPoint(x: tableView.frame.midX, y: tableView.frame.maxY)
let converted = tableView.convert(point, from: tableView.superview)
let indexPathForBottomCell = tableView.indexPathForItem(at: converted)
```

This should work too, and may be easier to understand. All the additional spaces (like bottom inset) would be handled differently for each case.