# Swift 4: Pagination using data from an array to make API call as user scrolls

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, api, uitableview

**Background**

In my app, I store a bunch of object IDs. I use these IDs to make batch API calls. The API limits each call to 10 ID numbers.   This data is rendered on a UITableView. The user can add and delete objects, which adds or removes the object ID from the database.

I’m using a Firestore database to store the object IDs on my end.

**Current Implementation**

Here’s what I’ve implemented so far, but it crashes the app when add & deleting objects. I haven’t been able to work out how to properly handle these cases & whether this is the right pattern to do something like this.

1. Get object IDs to be used for making API calls

```swift
var objectIds: [String] = []
var chunkedObjectIds: [[String]] = []
var objects: [Array] = []
var offset: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidload()

    getObjectIds()

 }

func getObjectIds() {
    // get objects IDs and store then in objectIds from the Firestore database
    // setup the .addSnapshotLister so the query is triggered whenever there is a change in the data on Firestore for the collection

    return chunkedObjectIds

    // when finished, get the first 10 objects from the 3rd party API

    fetchObjects()

}
```

2. Take object Ids array, split into array of arrays (lots of 10) & Make the API call for the first 10

```swift
func fetchObjects() {

     // split objectIds array in array of arrays, in lots of 10
     // chunkedObjectIds is set here

     // request the objects for the first 10 ID numbers

    Alamofire.request(… parameter with first 10 object ids …) (objects) in {

        // save objects

        // increment the offset
        offset += 1
    }

}
```

3. Render the data on the UITableView cells
4. Use the following method to load more data from the 3rd party API:

```swift
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let lastRow = objects.count 

        var parameters = [String: Any]()

        if indexPath.row == lastRow {
            if !(offset == self.chunkedObjectIds.count) {

                // process the next batch from the array
                parameters["id-numbers"] = self.chunkedObjectIds[offset].map{String($0)}.joined(separator: ",")

                Alamofire.request(… paramaters: parameters) { (objects) in
                    for item in 0..<objects.count {
                        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: item + self.objects.count, section: 0)
                        self.paths.append(indexPath)
                    }
                    self.objects.append(contentsOf: objects)
                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.tableView.insertRows(at: self.paths, with: .automatic)
                    self.tableView.endUpdates()
                    self.paths.removeAll()
                    self.offset += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

5. Adding or deleting objects:

   - The object ID is added or deleted from the Firestore database
   - The objectIds, chunkedObjectIds, offset and objects are cleared
   - The listener triggers a read of the data and the process repeats

**The Issue & Question**

This works well to load initial data. But duplication occurs when adding (and sometimes crashing). When deleting the app will crash because of out of range exceptions.

**Is this the correct pattern to use in the first place? If so, what am I missing to handle cases after the first load, specifically the addition and deletion of new object IDs.**

### Edit

I have changed the implementation based on feedback in the comments. So now, the process is like this:

1. Setup listener to get data from Firestore
2. Loop through the object ids from Firestore and while the counter is < 10 or we reach object.count - Now I save the next offset and the next time it triggers this method, I initiate a loop from the next offset with the same while conditions
3. Fetch the objects from the 3rd party API
4. I kept using `willDisplay cell` method to trigger more data to load - it seemed to work more reliably than `scrollDidEnd` method.

So now the app doesn't crash anymore. There are some issues with the firestore listener, but I'll post that as a separate question.

Comment: Instead of creating an array of arrays, why don't you remember the last fetched object and get the index of it and fetch the next 10?

Comment: try to divide and conquer. Mean first implement pagination correctly. Then try to implement add or delete. this will make your life easier. Secondly, i prefer to use scrollView delegate function `scrollViewDidEndDragging ` for detecting end of tableView and reload more data. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5137943/7698092). BTW, I prefer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17860149/7698092) approach

Comment: https://github.com/alfianlosari/SWPaginationIOS , i have try it

Comment: @SachinVas I ended up using that method instead, it's a much better way! Thanks.

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz - Thanks for the tip... I tried that method, but I went back to ```WillDisplay cell``` - I felt it works slightly better.

Comment: @PujiWahono - Good method. In my case I don't get any next offset or next url from the API to use for the next call.