# Firestore listener is fetching more data than the number of documents that exists

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fetching data from Firestore and setting up a listener. The data is stored in an array that is later used in API calls. I only want to append new data to this array. I have setup a listener for only "added" changes to the document.

Here is what I have implemented so far:

```swift
        db.collection("name").whereField("id", isEqualTo: id).addSnapshotListener({ (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else { return }

            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach({ (change) in
                if change.type == .added {
                    do {
                        for document in snapshot.documents {
                            // decode method code is shown below
                            let object = try document.decode(as: Object.self)
                            self.objectArray.append(object)
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            })
        })
```

Decode method

```swift
func decode<T: Decodable>(as objectType: T.Type, includingId: Bool = true) throws -> T {

        var documentJson = data()
        if includingId {
            documentJson?["id"] = documentID
        }

        let documentData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: documentJson, options: [])
        let decodedObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(objectType, from: documentData)

        return decodedObject
    }
```

For my test data, I only have 10 documents in the Firestore collection, but the array ends up having 100 objects in it on the first read.

It should be 10 and only new data is appended every time a write occurs on that Firestore collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over both `snapshot.documentChanges` and `snapshot.documents` within that same loop.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with these nested loops, but it doesn't make any sense to me.  If you want to know how many documents came back from a query, just look at `snapshot.documents`, as it will contain the entire set.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'm using this as part of the solution I posted about here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55294398/4466636 -- Now it's working, i.e. it returns the right number of documents. But when I add more objects to firestore, the UITableView refreshes with only 1 row, even though the array has the right number of objects.